# TLS / SSL server hello in reuse mode

Tags: ssl

Does anyone know how many times would server try to send hello back to client, after client has sent the hello, before giving up and closing the session( if SSL id is reused)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know how many times would server try to send hello back to client, after client has sent the hello, before giving up and closing the session( if SSL id is reused)?

At the TLS/SSL level, the server will only send `ServerHello` once, and it won't 'give up and close the session' at all. It may give up and close the *connection*, if it has a read timeout set on the socket: otherwise it can just sit there forever waiting for the next part of the handshake from the client.

At the TCP level it could happen several times if the client doesn't ACK it, but I don't think that's what you're asking about.

SSL session resumption has nothing to do with it.